# What does the Z part of transform-origin actually mean?

Tags: css, 3d, css-transforms

I'm trying to understand what exactly is the`Z offset` part in the `transform-origin` rule (the 3rd property).

I've set [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs28spwh/) .
It's a rotated red square inside a blue container. The container is rotated in a way that you can look at it "from the side".
Play with it using the developer tools or in JSFiddle.

If the `rotateX` value of the square is `0` then changing the Z part of `transform-origin` doesn't do anything - it doesn't affect the square, but any other rotation degrees values for `rotateX` will make it change -

But it is not clear what exactly is the change;
On which axis does it "move" when you play with the Z offset of `transform-origin`, and what is the relation between it and the value of `rotateX`?

I'm looking for both a satisfying conceptual explanation and a mathematical one...

Comment: CSS3 3D Transforms have 3 axis X, Y and Z

Comment: [On this site](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/), you can see the transformation on the z-axis, just tick `Debug`

Comment: @Aroniaina, yeah I know, you can make them with `translateX, translateY, translateZ, or translate3D`, but `transform-origin` is... something else.